# Oracle Database Recovery Problem

Tags: oracle, import

I am very new to Oracle, and trying to restore a oracle 8i database on win 2000 server.

- I have one week old database backup (backup taken with exp command), and i want to restore it now.
- Now I am unable to login through sqlplus (got shutdown in progress error)
- I have a backup and i want to restore it, but oracle is not starting at all, and 'imp' command is failing.

I started sqlplus / as sysdba  and following is the log of what i am trying to do. Can some one guide me further.

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
ORA-01109: database not open    

Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  143423516 bytes
Fixed Size                    75804 bytes
Variable Size              58105856 bytes
Database Buffers           85164032 bytes
Redo Buffers                  77824 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option for database open


SQL> shutdown immediate;
ORA-01109: database not open


Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  143423516 bytes
Fixed Size                    75804 bytes
Variable Size              58105856 bytes
Database Buffers           85164032 bytes
Redo Buffers                  77824 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option for database open


SQL> alter database open resetlogs;
alter database open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01245: offline file 1 will be lost if RESETLOGS is done
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'C:\ORACLE\ORADATA\ABCD\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

Comment: is there any way , i can delete all data files, and import my old backup ?

Comment: Do you know what corruption has occurred? What are you trying to fix with reverting to the week-old exp?

Answer (score 1):

EXP and IMP are not 'backups'. They are copies of data.
They expect to be imported into an operational database (often with users, grants and tablespaces already existing). You could try to get your existing database operational, but whether that is possible depends on what caused it to break in the first place. If you've lost important things like the datafiles for the system tablespace and don't have copies, then give up on it.

As advised by DCookie, you'd probably be best off creating a new database and importing into that.

You don't say whether the export is for the entire database or specific schemas, or whether you have non-schema objects (eg PUBLIC SYNONYMS).

If you have a full database export, then I'd recommend creating an 8i database and doing a full database import (which will include non-schema objects, users, tablespaces etc). Adding a database version upgrade would, IMHO, complicate things.

If you have schema exports, then you can look at a later version of Oracle as you have to to create the users, roles, tablespaces etc to get things loaded anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement to stay with 8i? You can simply create an empty database with 11g or 10g and import the 8i database export into it, and then you'll be relatively current. Otherwise, you can create an empty 8i database as well and use import.

Run the Oracle Database Configuration Assistant. From there you can create a database instance fairly easily.